# Implement HTML 5 Semantics on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html, semantics

Hello I have a wordpress site than I want to upgrade to HTML5 code

The following image shows the tags than i place for the structure, I want to know if they are correct.

http://i44.tinypic.com/14kjlep.png

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks all good except for the `aside` tags.

> "For content that is not the primary focus of an article (or page) but is still related to the article (or page), aside is what you need, regardless of its visual design."

I would say that advertising is not related to the articles. I would just use a div. But I guess in theory advertising could be related to the articles, so it's your choice.